# NVIDIA Control Panel not working

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

My NVIDIA Control Panel stopped working. At first it wouldn't start so I tried reinstalling it and doing bunch of things that most people on internet tell you to do, including reinstalling your drivers(having the newest ones), updating windows, disable/renable the graphics card driver, reinstalling the control panel, making a path, everything and nothing seems to work. I checked the NVIDIA Control Panel path and noticed that I'm missing the Control Panel Client folder and it just won't show up whenever I try to download it?

Comment: What exactly were those things? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: What is your graphic card and which NVIDIA driver have you installed? This folder is usually found in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Control Panel Client`. If you're missing it, have you tried to reinstall the NVIDIA driver?

Comment: May or may not be related but I had somewhat similar issue. The root cause of the problem was that Windows Firewall service was somehow disabled. After I enabled it, NVidia Control Panel started working fine. Just check if applicable.

Comment: @harrymc My graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 and I installed the newest driver available from the GeForce Experience. I'm aware that the folder is usually found there but it's just missing, and yes like I said i tried reinstalling the driver.

Comment: There's not much in this folder. The only useful file is `NvGpuUtilization.exe`. You may possibly have this file elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried choosing "Custom" > "Perform Clean Installation" when re-installing your NVIDIA Driver? And then heading to the microsoft store to re-install NVIDIA Control Panel?